# How do I create a UserControl in ASP.NET MVC from a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, user-controls, razor

Let's say I wanted to create a user control from a raw string rather than a .ascx file, how would I do that? Temp files are not an option. Is this even possible? I can't find anything online about this.

Bonus: How would I do this with the new razor engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use VirtualPathProvider to provide the text for the controls. Example: http://www.thecodinghumanist.com/Content/VirtualPathProviderExample.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think you just move out from normal asp.net to this MVC just like me.

In asp.net mvc, we uses HTML helper like `@Html.ActionLink()`, `@Html.CheckBox()` and `@Html.CheckBox()` you can add your own extension like `@Html.Grid()` by create a class like this:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyNamespace.Helpers
{
     public static class GridExtensions
     {
          public static string Grid(this HtmlHelper helper, <any parameter you think to generate the html>)
          {
               // render the html table here based on the parameter
          }
     }
}
```

Put this class file in a Helpers folder under root if you like. See [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs) to create custom extension. You can find the best jQuery like [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) and implement it in the extension.

If you think extension is not suitable you can use your own class with format @class.method() to return the string of html. Don't forget to use @using MyNamespace in the beginning of the vcshtml view file OR in the ~/View/web.config just besides the Razor assembly name to make sure the class or extension available. It will support intellisense also.

If you want to define the "UserControl" in the same *.cshtml file because it just specific to the view, just use `@helper function()` as ScottGu said [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx) it will minimize the code in the page by just calling `@function()`.

asp.net and asp.net mvc is totally different in term of `Control`. You can't use any control from normal asp.net into asp.net mvc.

**Edit**: Some typo and add more info.

Comment: What is the user control I want to render is rendering another user control using RenderPartial?

Comment: I can't get your question but partial views can be either .aspx or .ascx files so in Razor you can have .cshtml partial view same like the view itself. partial view is only view in html/razor (or html/asp.net <%%>) format to make common html/razor shared accross another views. Look about partial view here http://rachelappel.com/razor/partial-views-in-asp-net-mvc-3-w-the-razor-view-engine/

Answer (score 0):

You could use custom HTML helper for this, couldn't you?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Templated Razor Delegates](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx). Seems it is what you need